# Magnific-Popup Gallery with two image tag in a single a tag

Tags: javascript, html, magnific-popup

I'm making a gallery with Magnific-Popup but for speed up my website i've inside the a tag two different image. One for big screen and another one for small screen. I'm hidding one or the other one image with bootstrap class (hidden-lg hidden-md & hidden-sm hidden-xs).

The problem is that when i click on the a tag to open the image gallery, Magnific-Popup try to open hidden image and return "the image could not be loaded".

```html
<li>
  <figure>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <a href="assets/upload/images/romantic/clem-onojeghuo-193397.jpg" title="" class="gallery-item">
        <img src="/assets/image-cache/romantic/clem-onojeghuo-193397.5ddf5942.jpg" alt="" class="hidden-lg hidden-md">
        <img src="/assets/image-cache/romantic/clem-onojeghuo-193397.36620614.jpg" alt="" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <div class="gallery-caption">
          <div class="centrize">
            <div class="v-center"><i class="hc-search"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </figure>
</li>
```

```js
$('.gallery-item').magnificPopup({
  type: 'image',
  gallery:{
    enabled:true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my own error because i've two time the "gallery-item" class. One on the div tag and the other on the a tag.